# Category of entire relations

Tags: ct.category-theory

> Is there a reference that talks about the category ${\bf EntRel}$ whose objects are sets and whose arrows are entire relations?

As a preliminary observation ${\bf EntRel}$ is complete and cocomplete, with products and coproducts as in ${\bf Set}$ and equalizers/coequalizers defined by identical class-builder formulas and constructions as in ${\bf Set}$, except we interpret the variables in the formulae as second order (so $f(x)$ denotes a nonempty subclass instead of an element).

The motivation is understanding how well behaved entire relations are, in contrast  with functions, as morphisms between classes. Any thoughts or references are appreciated.

Comment: Possibly this category goes under the name of "category of sets and multivalued functions"?

Comment: Isn't it the same of the Kleisli category of the powerset monad?

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti I believe the standard ${\bf Rel}$ is the Kleisli category of the powerset monad, at least [according to the nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Rel#LimitsAndColimit).

Comment: @SamHopkins Good guess, but I am unable to find anything under this name after a brief search (an old MSE question where the author allows the relations not to be entire, but nothing about entire relations as the morphisms).

Comment: It's the Kleisli category of the monad that sends a set to the set of all non-empty subsets of it ("non-empty powerset monad").

Comment: @MarttiKarvonen Does this monad act on the category of sets with the empty set removed? Or is it the identity on the empty set?

Comment: Good point. Luckily either of the options you mention results in a monad. To get the correct Kleisli category, you'll need to send the empty set to itself.